# Axios - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on long lasting requests

Tags: timeout, axios

I have a REST backend for executing Selenium UI test. Sending a GET request with test names executes them and returns the result. The problem is that running some of these tests takes a long time, often over 5 minutes or more.

When I try to run a lengthy set of tests, after about 2 minutes I get an error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

The server seems to be working correctly. When I tried to send the request from Insomnia, I get correct response even after more than 5 minutes of running.

My code for sending the GET request

```
handleRunTests = (tests) => {
    const httpClient = axios.create();
    httpClient.defaults.timeout = 60 * 60 * 1000; // one hour timeout for running tests

    this.setState({
        testsResults: {},
        testsRunning: true
    });
    let url = `/api/runTests?tests=${tests}`;

    httpClient.get(url)
        .then(result => {... handle test results ...} 
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({
                testsRunning: false,
                error
            });
        })
};
```

Comment: This is i think antivirus issue. Disable it and try.

Comment: did you try `axios.create({timeout: 60 * 60 * 1000})`?

Comment: I did, unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: did you find a resolution? I have the same issue..